# ng-if condition using specificities in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to use the ng-if condition with `a == condition`?
Like `--ng-if='id = 1'`? Here is how I''m using it:

```
.col-md-3(ng-repeat="user in refs.userList | orderBy : 'department.id'", ng-if="user.department.id")
```

I want to display only users which are from the departement id number `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only users which are from the departement id number 1

Use the `==` operator as you've suggested; not the assignment (`=`) as you've attempted:

```
ng-if="user.department.id == 1"
```